# Increasing ACCEPT command entry font size

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

Visual FoxPro barcode scanner application uses accept command for barcode collection via RDP:

```
_screen.FontSize=20
_screen.FontName='Arial'
DO WHILE .T.
accept 'Barcode' to cBarCode
if empty(cBarCode)
  exit
  endif
insert into barcodes value (cBarCode)
ENDDO
```

Scanned barcode font size is too small:

[image]

How to increase displayed scanned barcode 123456 font size?

Only ACCEPT prompt font size can changed.
Re-writing application using @ GET commands or Forms is huge work.
Answer in
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c3f9e89a-8917-4236-bc2c-474592f1af4c/increase-font-size-on-accept-input-and-wait?forum=visualfoxprogeneral

recommends to use INPUTBOX() but this hides whole mobile screen.

Maybe there is FoxPro code for command line data entry which uses INKEY() or something other to mimics this command?
Or can some Windows api function or external dll called for this?

Comment: Documentation clearly states that "the character data you enter appears in 9 point FoxFont."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may replace the `accept` command by the following code

```
    LOCAL M.Lastkey
    M.Lastkey = 0
    cBarCode = ""
    ? 'Barcode'
    DO WHILE .T.
        M.Lastkey = INKEY(0)
        ?? CHR(M.Lastkey)
        IF M.Lastkey != 13
            cBarCode = cBarCode + CHR(M.Lastkey)
        ELSE
            EXIT
        ENDIF
    ENDDO
```

So the complete code will look link:

```
    _screen.FontSize=20
    _screen.FontName='Arial'
    DO WHILE .T.
        LOCAL M.Lastkey
        M.Lastkey = 0
        cBarCode = ""
        ? 'Barcode'
        DO WHILE .T.
            M.Lastkey = INKEY(0)
            ?? CHR(M.Lastkey)
            IF M.Lastkey != 13
                cBarCode = cBarCode + CHR(M.Lastkey)
            ELSE
                EXIT
            ENDIF
        ENDDO
        if empty(cBarCode)
          exit
          endif
        insert into barcodes value (cBarCode)
    ENDDO
```

Answer (score 0):

Andrus, Not sure about how to change/set the font but with regard to how to get the input from the scanner, I use the form's KeyPress method. Perhaps doing it this way would allow you to change the font on your form without any effect from your code that captures the barcode.

I have a property of the form, cpos_keypresses where the characters from the scanner are accumulated until the key code for Enter (13) is encountered. I am allowing only certain characters to be scanned.:

```
LPARAMETERS     tnKeyCode,  tnShiftAltCtrl

IF tnKeyCode = 13
   IF NOT EMPTY(thisform.cpos_keypresses)
      && process what has been collected in cpos_keypresses   ...
   ENDIF

   && Reset property to empty for next scan
   thisform.cpos_keypresses=""
ELSE
   && append the character to cpos_keypresses: (0-9) ascii 48-57 or dash(-) ascii 45 or A-Z ascii 65-90
   IF (tnKeyCode >= 48 AND tnKeyCode <= 57) OR tnKeyCode = 45 OR (tnKeyCode >= 65 AND tnKeyCode <= 90)
      thisform.cpos_keypresses=ALLTRIM(thisform.cpos_keypresses)+CHR(tnKeyCode)
   ENDIF
ENDIF

NODEFAULT
RETURN
```